From memory buffer to disk as fast as possible
I would like to present a scenario and discuss suitable design patterns to address it.
Consider a simple situation: a camera records to a memory buffer for ten seconds before stopping. Once recording ends, a binary file descriptor opens, and data is transferred to disk.
A major limitation of this approach is that recordings are restricted by the available RAM size. But, frame loss may not be a problem.
To mitigate this, one potential solution is to use a dedicated thread or process for writing to disk. In this setup, the producer memory buffer is shared between the main and writer threads/processes. However, this introduces a new issue: when the writer thread locks the buffer, the camera may be unable to place new frames, leading to potential frame loss.
Question
Is there a design pattern that addresses the problem highlighted in the second scenario?
Below some code examples for the two scenarios in Python.
First scenario in Python:
import io
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import Encoder as NullEncoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput

# Init camera
cam = Picamera2()

# Init memory buffer
mem_buff = io.BytesIO()
mem_out = FileOutput(mem_buff)

# Open camera
cam.start()

# Just writes frames without encoding i.e.: BGR888
encoder = NullEncoder()

# Recording time
to_record = 10
print(f"Start recording for {to_record} seconds")
cam.start_recording(encoder, mem_out)
time.sleep(to_record)
cam.stop_recording()
print("Finish recording")
cam.close()

# Begin data transfer to disk
out_fpath = "video.bin"
disk_transfer_start = time.perf_counter()
with open(out_fpath, "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(mem_buff.getvalue())
disk_transfer_el = time.perf_counter() - disk_transfer_start
print(f"Data transfer took {disk_transfer_el} sec")

# Get a sense of how many frames are missing
totbytes = os.path.getsize(out_fpath)
byteel = 2304*1296*3 # (frame_width * frame_height * num_channels)
num_frames = totbytes / byteel
print(f"Video has {num_frames} frames")

A possible implementation of the second scenario in Python:
import io
from threading import Thread, Event, Lock
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import Encoder as NullEncoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput

def disk_writer(mem_buff: io.BytesIO, bin_fd, write_interval: int, stop_event: Event, lock: Lock):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        start_loop = time.perf_counter()
        lock.acquire()
        curr_buff_pos = mem_buff.tell()
        lock.release()
        if curr_buff_pos > 0:
            lock.acquire()
            bin_fd.write(mem_buff.getvalue())
            mem_buff.seek(0)
            mem_buff.truncate(0)
            lock.release()
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start_loop
        if elapsed < write_interval:
            time.sleep(write_interval - elapsed)
    if mem_buff.tell() > 0:
        bin_fd.write(mem_buff.getvalue())
        mem_buff.seek(0)
        mem_buff.truncate(0)

# Init camera
cam = Picamera2()

# Init memory buffer
mem_buff = io.BytesIO()
mem_out = FileOutput(mem_buff)

# Get output file descriptor
bin_fd = open("video.bin", "wb")

# Open camera
cam.start()

# Create writing thread and start
stop_event = Event()
lock = Lock()
write_interval = 5
writer_thread = Thread(target=disk_writer, args=(mem_buff, bin_fd, write_interval, stop_event, lock))
writer_thread.start()

# Just writes frames without encoding i.e.: BGR888
encoder = NullEncoder()

# Recording time
to_record = 10
print(f"Start recording for {to_record} seconds")
cam.start_recording(encoder, mem_out)
time.sleep(to_record)
cam.stop_recording()
print("Finish recording")
stop_event.set()
writer_thread.join()
cam.close()
bin_fd.close()


# Get a sense of how many frames are missing
totbytes = os.path.getsize(out_fpath)
byteel = 2304*1296*3 # (frame_width * frame_height * num_channels)
num_frames = totbytes / byteel
print(f"Video has {num_frames} frames")


I don't want to ruin your fun but the documentation (Chapter 7, capturing videos) shows a pretty easy and straightforward example how to capture a video directly to the disk. I see no need to care about any low-level stuff.

Thank you for pointing such an obvious thing out! I had run some tests. Camera was set to record a 10s@55 FPS video. Saving directly to disk yields a video with ~430 frames. On the other hand, when running a program like in the first scenario the video produced has consistently 550 frames, that is, no frames were missed. Thanks. @Jeyekomon

What is bin_fd? (You're using it without having defined it.)

Right! Edited the post to include it. Its the file descriptor for the binary output file. Thanks for pointing that out @nocomment

Thanks. That's what I suspected, but my answer depended on it so I had to be sure (plus your code wouldn't work without it). Though I just deleted my answer because it also relies on your lock. I thought your camera recorder respected it, i.e., doesn't write to the buffer without acquiring the lock itself (you also said "the writer thread locks the buffer"). But looking closer, it doesn't seem to actually do that. Am I overlooking it? What's the connection? Is there more code missing?

Before answering I would like to mention that I am not an expert in concurrent programming. With that being said, I just acquire the lock on the writer thread so to prevent the camera to place more pictures on it and avoid "dirty reads". Is not that sufficient? Why? @nocomment

No, that is not sufficient. Acquiring the lock is useless if the other thread ignores it. The other thread would need to acquire it as well, then that acquiring would block until the lock is released by the thread that currently has it acquired.

You null-encoded frame is 230412963 bytes which is 9MB. If you try and write 55 fps to disk, you would require 500MB/s of disk bandwidth to keep up. You would actually be lucky to get 100MB/s to an SD card or 500 MB/s sustained to an SSD. Consider using YUV420 instead of RGB888 to halve the bandwidth required (with some loss of colour accuracy) or (M)JPEG encoding if you can accept the lower quality.

@MarkSetchell Aren't there plenty of SSDs that easily write thousands of MB/s?

@nocomment Indeed there are. The SSD is not the limiting factor though - it is the PCIe interface on the Raspberry Pi. It is Gen 2, so limited to around 500MB/s. You can force Gen 3, but that is not officially supported and still will max out around 900MB/s absolute maximum - which doesn't mean OP will get that or even close to it.

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2023/testing-pcie-on-raspberry-pi-5

My recommendation would be to simply use a SSD with DRAM-cache instead of an SD-card.
Just write the data to disk without a memory buffer and let the cache handle it.
This is a very straightforward solution, it should provide predictable results so that you can dial in the rate at wich you write data to disk without overwhelming the cache.
If you simply have to use an SD-card you can influence the behaviour of the OS-level disk cache (assuming you are using Raspbian) by editing an option file in fstab.
Take a look at this post from the official raspberry forum to get an idea of how to influence the disk cache:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=157743#p1026791

I've changed my /etc/fstab entry of my SSD to include ",commit=". I've recorded 10s@55FPS with different values of commit and checked how many frames were actually saved to disk. Results:commit=5 (default): 430 frames; commit=10: 510-520 frames. commit=20: 530-540; commit=600: 520-550. Definitely there is some improvement!
